# org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Unable to serialize record

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, avro

After upgrading the service from spring boot 2.8 to 3.5 and few additional maven dependencies along with it, I get the following error when running the service:

```
2023-10-13 09:07:10.272 ERROR
                2893856 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.TaskExecutor        
                : stream-thread [prd2171-product-typer-intqa2-d3a50bb9-1936-4ad2-8207-1452971b61fe-StreamThread-1] Failed to process stream task 0_0 due to the following error: 
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Unable to serialize record. ProducerRecord(topic=[contaq.prd2171.event.patch.intqa2], partition=[null], timestamp=[1697180830225]
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:231)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:85)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:228)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamTransformValues$KStreamTransformValuesProcessor.process(KStreamTransformValues.java:66)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:157)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:228)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:159)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:228)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:159)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:228)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:159)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:228)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:159)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:228)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamMapValues$KStreamMapProcessor.process(KStreamMapValues.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:159)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:228)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:159)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:228)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:159)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:228)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:159)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:228)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$doProcess$1(StreamTask.java:810)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:867)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.doProcess(StreamTask.java:810)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:741)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskExecutor.processTask(TaskExecutor.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskExecutor.process(TaskExecutor.java:78)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.process(TaskManager.java:1747)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:807)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:617)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:579)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:144)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:61)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer.serialize(SpecificAvroSerializer.java:65)
    at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerializer.serialize(SpecificAvroSerializer.java:38)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:197)
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:122)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:91)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.newInstance(UriBuilder.java:69)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromPath(UriBuilder.java:111)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:505)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:499)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:472)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:213)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:275)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:251)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:103)
    ... 74 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:62)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:155)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:105)
    ... 84 common frames omitted
```

It actually operates ok until is comes across specific message case I guess.
I tried adding maven dependency for java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But it fixed nothing.